# splitting array into sub array, then checking size of each element

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio

This is a little bit complicated, so forgive me in advance if I dont articulate it properly. I have a datatable that returns pipe delimited data, formatted to be so in the stored procedure the datatable pulls from. Example: ABC|11/30/2017|1234-56-7981-5678---91|STRING|1234.56|

I have split the rows into an array, separated by each pipe, using this code:

```
    string[] curValueArrary = curValue.Split('|');
```

Now this separates each row into an array with 6 parts. One of these parts is separated by dashes, as you can see above: ("1234-56-7891..."). The entire block of code I use to do this is:

```
foreach (DataRow curRow in Datatable.Rows)
{
    curValue = curRow["Column_Name"].ToString();
    string[] curValueArrary = curValue.Split('|');

if (curValueArrary.Length != 6)
   throw new Exception("Error data row: " + curValue);
   else if (curValueArrary[2].Length < 22)
   throw new Exception("Error data: " + curValue);
```

This returns an array that looks like this:

```
[0]ABC
[1]11/30/2017
[2]1234-56-7891-5678-91
[3]STRING
[4]1234.56
[5]""
```

As you can see, this checks to make sure the array consists of 6 rows, and that the [2] row has 22 characters in it. NOW TO MY QUESTION: I need to dissect this array even further, and make sure that each dash-separated value in the [2] row of the array, is a specific length. For example, the first block of characters in the [2] row is "1234". How would I check that each time the array is being written, that the first block of characters in the second row ALWAYS has 4 characters in it? Whether its "1234" or "1010", that first set of characters should always have 4 characters in it. How do I check for that and then throw an exception if it has more or less? I would need to repeat this process for each block of characters in the [2] row. (ex. make sure the second block "**56**" has two characters, make sure the third block "**7891**" has 4 characters....etc..). Also please note that the code in question has to work inside of the code block I posted above.

THANK YOU! any help is appreciated

Comment: Why not just split the value and check the length of the index values, or use regex

Comment: Are you saying split the value of the [2] row and check the length of the index values? Can you explain in a little detail please? Im not very familiar with using .split() on a string to make an array. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply split again in a subarray and check the length of the elements accordingly.

Here an example, based on your code:

```
foreach (DataRow curRow in Datatable.Rows)
{
    curValue = curRow["Column_Name"].ToString();
    string[] curValueArrary = curValue.Split('|');

   if (curValueArrary.Length != 6)
      throw new Exception("Error data row: " + curValue);
   else if (curValueArrary[2].Length < 22)
      throw new Exception("Error data: " + curValue);
   else
   {
      var subArray = curValueArrary[2].Split('-');
      if (subArray[0].Length < 4)
         throw new Exception("Error sub data: " + subArray[0]);
      if(subArray[1].Length < 2)
         throw new Exception("Error sub data: " + subArray[1]);
      //and so on...
   }
}
```

Comment: YES. THANK YOU. this is exactly what I was looking for, I didnt know exactly how to write it out, when all along I just needed to add another "else" lol. Thank you so much.